# Do I need a visa for a short-term internship in Germany if I already hold a Schengen visa for a different country?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, schengen-visas

I am a non-EU student studying in a Scandinavian country. I have been offered a chance to do an internship in Germany which is less than 90 days. I hold a student residence permit (Schengen) for the country am studying in.

Do I need a work visa for Germany for the internship?

Comment: Is the internship paid?

Comment: @JonathanReez  no

Comment: If the company for which you will work doesn't ask you to apply for a visa, I'd just go regardless of the rules

Answer (score 1):

According to [Young Germany](http://www.young-germany.de/topic/work/jobs-career/interning-in-germany-the-basics):

> Do I need a visa if I am not from Germany?
>
> If you are an EU citizen, you don't need a work permit. If you are a
>   non-EU citizen, you do. **If you are studying and living outside Germany
>   and applying for an internship in Germany, you will need to organize a
>   work permit before you are allowed to undertake an internship.** You
>   will also need health insurance, which is compulsory for anyone
>   working in Germany, and necessary for getting a work permit.

Therefore the answer is **yes**, you will need a work permit before coming to Germany for work. However if your employer doesn't ask you to apply for one, you might as well get away with going to Germany on a regular visa, especially since the internship is unpaid.